# Как создать произвольную копию комментариев на wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на `wordpress`

Думаю как бы создать кастомный тип **отзывы** с функционалом точно таким же, как комментарии (сделать возможность отвечать на них), но при этом не смешивать их друг с другом: комментарии выводятся для постов, а отзывы размещаются на отдельной страничке.

Comment: Интересуюсь спросить, а зачем вам этот огород?

Comment: @Quazimorda вопроса не понял. Отзывы это отзывы (к услугам, например), комментарии это комментарии (к примеру, к статьям)

Comment: Всякое усложнение должно иметь цель. Никто не мешает вам включить комментарии не только для записей (post), но и для страниц (page) и так как все они выводятся там где и нужно (и не путаются друг с другом), то зачем их как-то отделять?

Comment: Зайди с другой стороны - разделяй комменты не при записи, а при выводе.

Comment: @Quazimorda цель в том, чтобы они не мешались в одном разделе, когда их будет превышать 100 штук. Т.е. отзывов, к примеру, 20 (они более важные), а комментов 500 и теперь чтобы найти какой-то определенный отзыв и на него ответить - предлагаете перебирать все комментарии пока до него не доберешься?

Comment: @Quazimorda такая задача иногда встречается. Речь как правило об удобствах в админке.

Comment: @SeVlad  а можете пояснить чуть подробнее?

Comment: Просто обычно в записи или странице выводятся не вообще все комментарии всего сайта, а только те из них, которые относятся к данной записи или странице.

Comment: @Вася см. Отзывы оставляются к товару (напр), а комменты - к постам. Это разные типы контента И в админке уже  сделать фильтры по типу конетнта. Как-то так.

Comment: Ну и ещё в шаблонах товара поменять текст "коммент" на "отзыв".